# How can I correct SQLite "No such table" in Next.js?

Tags: sqlite, next.js, knex.js

I am studying Next.js and when I was trying to pre-fetch data from a SQLite3 database I encountered the "SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: post" error.
I am certain that the table exists, I've ran a query to be certain and it did returned the expected result. The only other probability that I can think of is that I'm not referencing my database correctly.
I'm using Knex to connect with it.

Here's my code:

database/index.js:

```js
import knex from "knex"
import path from "path"

const database = knex({
    client: "sqlite3",
    connection: {
        filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "database.sqlite")
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true
})

export default database
```

libs/posts.js:

```js
import database from "../database"

export const getAllPostsIds = async () => {
    try {
        let fileNames = await database.select("title").from("post")

        return fileNames.map(fileName => {
            {
                params: {
                    id: fileName
                }
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            params: {
                id: "error: " + error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function call (pages/index.js):

```js
import Head from "next/head"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import { getAllPostsIds } from "../lib/posts"

export default function Home({ data }) {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Head>
                <title>Home</title>
            </Head>

            <section></section>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
    const data = await getAllPostsIds()
    
    return {
        props: {
            data
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant tree structure:

```
|components
|--|layout
|--|--index.js
|database
|--|index.js
|lib
|--|posts.js
|pages
|--|index.js
```

The error:

```
{
  params: {
   id: 'error: Error: select `title` from `post` - SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: post'
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the call to `getAllPostsIds`?

Comment: Edited, @felixmosh

Comment: Your code looks OK to me, Do you have the table in the SQLite file?

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

> you can't use __dirname as the path it will return will be different
> from the pages directory. Instead you can use `process.cwd()` which
> gives you the directory where Next.js is being executed.

```
import knex from "knex"
import path from "path"

// Add this line
const __dirname = path.resolve()

const database = knex({
    client: "sqlite3",
    connection: {
        filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "database.sqlite") // or -> path.join(process.cwd(), "database.sqlite")
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true
})

export default database
```

Comment: could you explain the difference and why your solution should work?

Comment: you can't use __dirname as the path it will return will be different from the pages directory.       Instead you can use `process.cwd()` which gives you the directory where Next.js is being executed.